# Funky behaviour of feof() under Windows

Tags: c, windows

So I’ve been writing a program which scans through files that works just fine when compiled with gcc and clang on Linux. But on Windows, with both Microsoft compiler and MinGW, feof() false-triggers. The loop should break once it detects the end statement of the filetype, the feof is only there as a failsafe and never triggers for correct files on Linux…

I had the programm print the filepointer location with ftell() and the values are just plain wrong. The EOF always triggers at 2^n values which are some orders of magnitude lower than the actual file size...

```
while(1)
    {
            ...
            //File is read here
            //normally breaks before EOF-check

            if(feof(in))
            {
                    DEBUG_PRINTF("Reached EOF before IEND\n");
                    break;
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

opening the File with "rb" instaed of "r" solved the problem

Comment: Show us a [mcve].

Comment: Did you open a binary file as if it were a text file?  Linux doesn't make a practical distinction, but Windows does.

Comment: Binary-mode solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened your file with `fopen(..., "r")`. It's a text file. `ftell()` is going to return the correct values to pass back to `fseek()` which are not the same as the the values as the number of bytes you read because the library is handling `\r\n` -> `\n` for you.

In addition, you either have opened a file >= 4GB (`msvcrt.dll` can't handle files that big) or have a 0x1A byte in the file.

Please note that linking against `msvcrt.dll` is the default when using `gcc` on Windows, and it's about the equivalent to Visual Studio 6 runtime. You probably don't want to link against it. It's really buggy. Alas [this question for how to not do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728544/how-to-avoid-msvcrt-dll-compiling-with-mingw-64-32-bits) is unanswered.