# How to use MinGW without linking to api-ms-win-core*.dll

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have an application in C++ that is using Qt framework and I want to cross compile it into a portable program for Windows. Since I don't have any computer or virtual box with Windows operating system (and I also don't have enough space on my disk to change that), I'm trying to use MinGW to cross compile. I've installed MinGW from the ArchLinux packages and the other required libraries from the AUR.

However, everytime I try to compile the program, it would link to `api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll` and `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll`. Windows users then complain about seeing error messages like

> The procedure entry point `CreateEventW` could not be located in the dynamic link library `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll`

or error message

> The program can't start because `api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll` is missing from your computer

My understanding is that these are windows-internal apis and that I shouldn't be linking to them. Can someone tell my why does MinGW link to these libraries and can I tell it to stop linking to these?

Comment: It links to msvc runtime. Old post but I think its related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301995/windows-gnu-compiler-suite-without-external-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301995/windows-gnu-compiler-suite-without-external-dependencies)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728544/how-to-avoid-msvcrt-dll-compiling-with-mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728544/how-to-avoid-msvcrt-dll-compiling-with-mingw64)

Comment: @drescherjm it does link to `msvcrt.dll` as well and I'm fine with anything that's present on Windows 7 and above, but I need to not link those api-ms-win-core-* libraries

Comment: @drescherjm When running [`i686-w64-mingw32-ldd`](https://github.com/xantares/mingw-ldd) those api libraries show up already. I'm fine if those weren't in the binary but loaded by msvcrt at runtime, but this unfortunately does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: I think this explains the dlls you are mentioning better: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/windows-7-64-bit-dll-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/windows-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm pretty sure I asked a windows user to install microsoft visual c++ redistributable stuff before, but also I'm not using a MSVC toolchain so I wouldn't expect that to necessarily fix it

Comment: You have to install the correct version that matches the mingw